# Adobe Air Application HTTPS Security Popup

Tags: security, ssl, actionscript, air, popup

I have an Air Application which communicates quite often with our server.  Usually, all communication is fine, but every once in a while I get the following popup:  "Revocation information for the security certificate for this site is not available.  Do you wan to proceed?

Unfortunately, this popup halts all communications until the end user clicks OK (which is a problem as this application does not allow for user interaction and is not accessible locally.

I am connecting to our website which has a valid Comodo SSL certificate.  Visiting the website causes no popups for any kind and shows completely valid.

I also have a Comodo Software Certificate validating the application which is bundled with the  program.

I am using actionscript HTTP services to communicate with the server with GET/POST calls.

```
checkInService = new HTTPService();
checkInService.concurrency = Concurrency.SINGLE;
checkInService.method = "POST";
checkInService.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT,sendResult);
checkInService.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, faultResult);
checkInService.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE, invokeAttempt);
checkInService.url = "https://www.mywebsite.com";
```

Unfortunately, when the certificate popup appears, it continues to popup for every call (which is on a 2 second timer), causing thousands of popups eventually crashing the program.

My thoughts are the following:
1. Ensure the Root Certificate is installed on the PC.
2. Install the website's certificate as a trusted certificate
3. Add the site to the Trusted Sites in Internet Options
4. Disable Publisher/Certification verification in Internet Options.

I want to leave as much security as possible.  Any hints or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revocation means, that the issuer of the certificate revoked it. Check for revocation is usually done after the trust path for the certificate was verified, so I assume that it is not a problem with the trust store on your system.

But, after the trust path verification so browser will check for revocation. Today this is mostly done with OCSP (online certificate status protocol). This needs an OCSP-URL in the certificate which can be asked and an OCSP responder at the issuers side, which responds to OCSP requests on this URL.

My guess is, that this is where the problem is, e.g. the following might be:

- the OCSP responder has no revocation information yet, because the certificate is to new (just wait some hours in this case)
- the OCSP responder has network or other problems (just wait and retry later)
- a firewall or similar on your site is blocking access to the OCSP responder (check your network or ask your administrator)

Comment: I ran charles to create a proxy and found that since the proxy does not trust the destination, it throws up the error.  Looks like the proxy just needs to trust the cert and things should work just fine.  I would assume the "ramdomness" of the popups was due to the lease of the cert.  Certifications are cached for a period of time.  From waht I read OCSP communicates on port 80 so I'm not sure if could be directly blocked, but the proxy sure does a number on things.

Comment: OCSP errors are unfortunately common and most browsers will do soft fails (at least on non-EV certificates), e.g. they will just assume everything is all right if they get no or no usable response back. Often this behavior can be changed (like security.OCSP.require setting in Firefox), but I don't know where Air gets its settings from.